# React Native - undefined is not an object(evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.state') even after installing and linking the package

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

Helllloooww,
I have an error when i try to run my app.
I already tried to do:

```
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
```

Then run:

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Tried also to do (to clean everything, install and link again):

```
rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/ && rm -f package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean --force && rm -rf ios/build/ && rm -rf ios/Pods/ && rm -f ios/Podfile.lock && npm install && cd ios && pod install && cd .. && react-native link
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes react-native link doesn't link properly. I would try to perform manual setup, assuming that there are instructions how to do it (setting android manifest and gradle files).

Comment: You'll need to configure MainActivity.java file as per this documentation https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Can u provide some code where its  happening